# test:TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not None Type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, argparse

I am trying to run this code in anaconda python3.7, but I'm getting below error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

This is for windows 10, running on  python 3.7

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from model import get_model
from utils.visualize import plot

def sigmoid(x):
return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='CLI for inference')
PARSER.add_argument('--file', type=str, help='Image on which to perform inference')
PARSER.add_argument('--savedmodel', type=str, default='model/iter-51042', 
help='SavedModel directory')
PARSER.add_argument('--k', type=int, default=5, help='Top K predictions to print')
PARSER.add_argument('--visualize', action='store_true', default=False, help='Whether to 
visualize <file>')
PARSER.add_argument("-f", "--fff", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()

FILE = ARGS.file
SAVED_MODEL = ARGS.savedmodel
K = ARGS.k
VISUALIZE = ARGS.visualize

pt_cloud = np.load(FILE)
pt_cloud = np.expand_dims(pt_cloud, axis=0)
```

So when I run python manage.py test trips.tests, I'm getting the this traceback error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22664/1093035628.py in <module>
 31 
 32 # Load point cloud
  ---> 33 pt_cloud = np.load(FILE)
 34 pt_cloud = np.expand_dims(pt_cloud, axis=0)
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Abdou_Env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in 
 load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
 405             own_fid = False
 406         else:
 --> 407             fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
 408             own_fid = True
 409 

 TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: How are you calling this script? It expects some command line arguments, are you passing those?